# How to not repeat the same operations in RxJava?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a code like following:

```java
authRepository.login(userName, password)
              .doOnSubscribe(__ -> apiProgress.setValue(ApiProgress.start()))
              .doFinally(() -> apiProgress.setValue(ApiProgress.stop()))
              .subscribe(login -> loginData.setValue(login), 
                           err -> apiError.setValue(ApiError.create(err)))
```

I need to repeat `doOnSubscribe(..)` and `doFinally` for all api calls.

Is there any way to achieve this thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

You can create something like this using `Transformer`  (http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Single.Transformer.html)

```
static <T> SingleTransformer<T, T> subscribeAndFinalTransformer() {
        return new SingleTransformer<T, T>() {
            @Override
            public SingleSource<T> apply(Single<T> upstream) {
                return upstream.doOnSubscribe(disposable -> {
                    // Your doOnSubscribe Block
                }).doFinally(() -> {
                    // Your doFinally Block 
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

and above reusable `Transformer` can be attached for all the `Single` using `compose` method.

```
authRepository.login(userName, password).compose(subscribeAndFinalTransformer())
.subscribe()

authRepository.anotherApi().compose(subscribeAndFinalTransformer()).subscribe()
```

if you are using `Observable` or `Completable`, you should use equivalent `Transformer` instead `SingleTransformer`

**EDIT:**

Above approach is convenient if you want to reuse some actions for only certain calls.

if you want to attach the actions to all of your API calls you can create Retrofit `CallAdapter`

```
class RxStreamAdapter implements CallAdapter {

    private final Class rawType;
    private final CallAdapter<Object, Object> nextAdapter;
    private final Type returnType;

    RxStreamAdapter(Class rawType,
                    Type returnType,
                    CallAdapter nextAdapter) {
        this.rawType = rawType;
        this.returnType = returnType;
        this.nextAdapter = nextAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public Type responseType() {
        return nextAdapter.responseType();
    }

    @Override
    public Object adapt(Call call) {
        if (rawType == Single.class) {
            return ((Single) nextAdapter.adapt(call))
                    .doOnSubscribe(getDoOnSubscribe())
                    .doFinally(getDoFinally());
        } else if (returnType == Completable.class) {
            return ((Completable) nextAdapter.adapt(call))
                    .doOnSubscribe(getDoOnSubscribe())
                    .doFinally(getDoFinally());
        } else {
            // Observable
            return ((Observable<Object>) nextAdapter.adapt(call))
                    .doOnSubscribe(getDoOnSubscribe())
                    .doFinally(getDoFinally());
        }
    }

    @NotNull
    private Consumer<Disposable> getDoOnSubscribe() {
        return disposable -> {

        };
    }

    @NotNull
    private Action getDoFinally() {
        return () -> {

        };
    }
}
```

And then add it while creating Retrofit Object (Before `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory`)

```
RetrofitApi retrofitApi = new Retrofit
                .Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(new CallAdapter.Factory() {
                    @Override
                    public CallAdapter<?, ?> get(Type returnType, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
                        CallAdapter<?, ?> nextAdapter = retrofit.nextCallAdapter(this, returnType, annotations);
                        Class<?> rawType = getRawType(returnType);
                        if (rawType == Single.class || rawType == Observable.class || rawType == Completable.class) {
                            return new RxStreamAdapter(getRawType(returnType), returnType, nextAdapter);
                        } else {
                            return nextAdapter;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()
```

You can also set hooks using `RxJavaPlugins`. But you cannot differentiate b/w normal stream and Retrofit stream.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering. It does solve the problem at some extent but now I need to call `compose(subscribeAndFinalTransformer())` every time I will call an api. Is there any alternative ?

Comment: Btw, you provided the answer of asked question so I am accepting your solution :).

Comment: @VatishSharma I hope you are using retrofit. I have updated the answer. I will still go with `compose()` instead `CallAdapter` due to flexibility. Again there are some cases you had to go with `Adapter` approach like when other developers might forget to attach the actions that needed for every call. In that case it would be helpful. Cheers !

Comment: Great! Thanks, this is exactly what I want to achieve.